Pyinstaller : FileNotFoundError: MultiplexedPath must contain at least one path
I am having an issue with PyInstaller when trying to bundle my Python IA script into an executable. I keep encountering the following error:
FileNotFoundError: MultiplexedPath must contain at least one path
Here is the full traceback:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1967, in __call__
  File "UX.py", line 99, in enter_key_event
  File "UX.py", line 44, in question
  File "UX.py", line 58, in execution_IA
  File "files\RAG_modif_pour_UX.py", line 249, in main
  File "files\RAG_modif_pour_UX.py", line 136, in add_to_chroma
  File "langchain_chroma\vectorstores.py", line 313, in __init__
  File "chromadb\__init__.py", line 334, in Client
  File "chromadb\api\client.py", line 58, in __init__
  File "chromadb\api\shared_system_client.py", line 19, in __init__
  File "chromadb\api\shared_system_client.py", line 30, in _create_system_if_not_exists
  File "chromadb\config.py", line 425, in instance
  File "chromadb\api\segment.py", line 124, in __init__
  File "chromadb\config.py", line 318, in require
  File "chromadb\config.py", line 425, in instance
  File "chromadb\db\impl\sqlite.py", line 74, in __init__
  File "importlib_resources\_common.py", line 46, in wrapper
  File "importlib_resources\_common.py", line 56, in files
  File "importlib_resources\_common.py", line 117, in from_package
  File "importlib_resources\future\adapters.py", line 65, in get_resource_reader
  File "importlib_resources\future\adapters.py", line 70, in _standard_reader
  File "importlib_resources\future\adapters.py", line 78, in _namespace_reader
  File "importlib_resources\readers.py", line 141, in __init__
  File "importlib_resources\readers.py", line 76, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: MultiplexedPath must contain at least one path

I had several, ModuleNotFound Error before that forced me to insert a lot of module in the hidden import of the spec files
I have tried specifying additional paths and using hidden imports with the following command:
pyinstaller --paths=/path/to/file  --hidden-import chromadb.db.impl.sqlite --hidden-import chromadb.api --hidden-import chromadb.config --hidden-import chromadb.api.client --hidden-import chromadb.migrations --hidden-import chromadb.migrations.embeddings_queue UX.py
I also clean my .spec
Despite this, I continue to encounter the same error. I have verified that all necessary files are in the specified directories.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you for your help!
my spec file:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['UX.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\xx\\HL-Documents\\python modif\\OLLAMA rag v2'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['chromadb.db.impl.sqlite', 'chromadb.api', 'chromadb.config', 'chromadb.api.client', 'chromadb.migrations', 'chromadb.migrations.embeddings_queue', 'importlib_resources'],
    hookspath=["\hooks"],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='UX',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)


some of my import
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import filedialog
import time
from time import sleep
import os
import shutil
from files import RAG_modif_pour_UX
from pydantic.deprecated import decorator
from chromadb.telemetry.product import posthog
from chromadb.api import segment
from langchain_ollama import OllamaEmbeddings
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_chroma import Chroma
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from langchain_community.document_loaders import OnlinePDFLoader
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough
import os
from langchain.schema.document import Document
import shutil
from chromadb.utils.embedding_functions.onnx_mini_lm_l6_v2 import ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2
import subprocess
import sys


I still got the same error, maybe it has a link with chroma ?

I was with the same problem and managed to solve.
I'm using poetry-pyinstaller-plugin, i just put the chromadb inside the collect section and did the trick
[tool.poetry-pyinstaller-plugin.collect]
all = [..., "chromadb"]

I guess if you put --collect-all chromadb in your pyinstaller command, will solve it.

OMG, thx so much, it worked.  I do the --collect-all chromadb and it worked. how did you figured out that ?

For completeness sake you can also add --hidden-import=chromadb.utils.embedding_functions.onnx_mini_lm_l6_v2.ONNXMiniLM_L6_V2. A user on Chroma discord confirmed this is working for them.
Ref: https://discord.com/channels/1073293645303795742/1308289061634707496
